# Ubuntu 14.04.4 installation and GParted fails to recognize windows partitions. Need help determining cause of this

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, windows-10

**I have tried to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 using a live USB, but GParted and the Ubuntu installation screen does not list any partitions (only lists the drives as sda, sdb, and sdc) and shows my 2 SSDs and 1 HDD as unallocated. I have tried looking at different posts on Ask Ubuntu, but none of them have helped. Any help would be great.**

1. My Laptop Details:

   - sda is a M.2 SSD with Windows 7 installed
   - sdb is a M.2 SSD with Windows 10 installed
   - sdc is a HDD with 2 partitions

     1. Partition containing data
     2. Partition where I wish to install Ubuntu

[My Paritions from Disk Management view on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98KjD.png)

I installed Windows 7 first, then installed Windows 10. Now I wish to triple boot with Ubuntu and I do not mind the GRUB boot loader but would prefer the Windows boot loader.

2. I tried running the **sudo fdisk -lu** command, but I am not sure how to interpret the data

   ```
   Script started on Mon 18 Apr 2016 05:01:44 AM UTC?
   ]0;it@it: ~?it@it:~$ sudo fdisk -lu?

   WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.?


   Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes?
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors?
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes?
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes?
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes?
   Disk identifier: 0x8683fc6c?

      Device Boot          Start                 End          Blocks   Id  System?
   /dev/sda1   *                2048          206847          102400        7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT?
   /dev/sda2                  206848   500115455   249954304        7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT?

   WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.?


   Disk /dev/sdb: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes?
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors?
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes?
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes?
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes?
   Disk identifier: 0x3f76ecea?

      Device Boot          Start                 End          Blocks   Id  System?
   /dev/sdb1                        2048   500115455   250056704        7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT?

   WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.?


   Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes?
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors?
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes?
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes?
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes?
   Disk identifier: 0x8683fc14?

      Device Boot          Start                 End          Blocks   Id  System?
   /dev/sdc1                        2048   329455615   164726784        6  FAT16?
   /dev/sdc2           329457664  1953519615   812030976        7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT?

   Disk /dev/sdd: 32.5 GB, 32463912960 bytes?
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3946 cylinders, total 63406080 sectors?
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes?
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes?
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes?
   Disk identifier: 0x00000000?

      Device Boot          Start                 End          Blocks   Id  System?
   /dev/sdd1   *                2048        63406079        31702016        c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)?
   ]0;it@it: ~?it@it:~$ exit?
   exit?

   Script done on Mon 18 Apr 2016 05:01:57 AM UTC
   ```
3. Other things worth mentioning

   - I previously had a RAID 0 with my 2 M.2 SSDs however, I have wiped my drives and reinstalled operating systems on it about 2 times since then
   - I once had Ubuntu installed on this computer, but I wiped my drives and installed other operating systems since then

**Any help would be great! Thanks.**